# How to run form input phone mask on load?

Tags: javascript

I am masking a phone input via typing like this:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById("phoneinput_<%= dom_id(field) %>").addEventListener('input', function (e) {
    var x = e.target.value.replace(/\D/g, '').match(/(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})/);
    e.target.value = !x[2] ? x[1] : '(' + x[1] + ') ' + x[2] + (x[3] ? '-' + x[3] : '');
  });
  </script>
```

When I am editing the form and the phone field values are pulled from the DB I also need to format them on load outside of the input event listener. How do you do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a `.dispatchEvent(new Event("input"))` to trigger an input:

```js
let elem = document.getElementById("phoneinput");
elem.addEventListener('input', function (e) {
  var x = e.target.value.replace(/\D/g, '').match(/(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})/);
  e.target.value = !x[2] ? x[1] : '(' + x[1] + ') ' + x[2] + (x[3] ? '-' + x[3] : '');
});
elem.dispatchEvent(new Event("input"));
```

```html
<input id="phoneinput" value="1234567890" />
```

Comment: Thanks. That does indeed work.